# AWS GreengrassCore 2: Sending Images using MQTT Protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

Greeting!
I have two greengrasscoreV2 devices, one running at floorshop taking images and sending to another core device in data center which runs inferrence and pushes the results to s3. Both of the devices reside in same greengrass group. Core device in floorshop does not have internet and communicates thru local network whrease Datacenter core device has access to internet

I am running into following issues. By default AWS MQTT client supports 128kb whrease image is around 800 kb. I can send smaller images (50kb) by converting into binary without any issue but larger images are never recived and constraint by limit size

In given context, I am looking for recommendations or best practice to opt for:

- use mosquitto for internal communication to send images from one
  device to another and manage mqtt client overhead. In mosquitto configuration we can set the message size
- setup a simple API endpoint in data center thru which i can forward images and read afterwards by pushing a message in topic
- send the images by dividing it into chunks. This will have additional overhead to maintain the sequence on both publisher and reciever

What would be better choice in context of GreengrassV2, any guidance will be appreicated